# tinyMce with typescript could not load skins

Tags: typescript, tinymce

I am trying to use tinyMce editor with TypeScript and in my Editor.ts file I have

```
var tinymce = require('tinymce');
require('tinymce/themes/silver');

require.context(
    'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]&context=node_modules/tinymce!tinymce/skins/',
    true,
    /.*/
);


// Initialize
$(function () {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea.multi-line',
         })
});
```

But no matter whart configurations I make in webpack I get

```
CssSyntaxError: C:\GIT\Core\WebApps\WebAdmin\Inbox.WebApps.WebAdmin.Publications\skins\content\dark\content.css:2:1: Unknown word
```

I will appreciate any help

Comment: I had the same error message. I commented out `OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin` in my webpack config and that made the error go away, but I do not have a real understanding of the issue.